# Windows Popup Errors

Tags: apache-2.2, windows

I have Apache running on a Windows Server.  Periodically error message will show up on the screen.  The message is this: **Apache HTTP Server encountered a problem and needed to Close**.  But the interesting thing is the errors are from months ago; it will say **The error occured on 05/29/2011 at 12:31pm**

Why is Windows reporting errors from long ago?  How can I stop this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows will keep track of interactive error messages that can't be displayed due to no interactive sessions existing at the time of the error.  Instead of just eating them they will be displayed the next time someone logs in interactively (ie- from the console or from a remote desktop session).  This happens because many apps will not log to Windows event logs and this is the only way for them to tell you that something (good or bad) happened.

Comment: Thank you - indeed they appear right after I start a Remote Desktop Session.  Is there anyway to explicitly delete them?

Comment: Do you mean so that they don't appear at all?  Not that I know of.  They should be all aggregated into a single window, though, so you can just close that one window.